# sync evolution contacts and calendar with owncloud

Tags: gnome, sync, evolution, owncloud-server

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and I would like to sync Evolution with Owncloud and my Android.

I have Android and Owncloud talking fine but the problem is with Evolution and Owncloud. I have probably 250 contacts in evolution and want them to sync with Owncloud and then later with my phone.

I used Gnomes online accounts to connect evolution with Owncloud and they talk fine. The problem I have however, is that Owncloud shows up in Evolution as a separate calendar and contacts (not merged with what I already have) that disappear whenever I am not connected to the internet. It is essentially an "Owncloud viewer" not really syncing anything like takes place on the Android-Owncloud side.

I am hoping that I can get this set up so that changes on any of the three will be pushed to all so it won't matter which one I use I have up to date information.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and want to add that at least the contacts do not even seem to update in Evolution: I've added some details on one in ownCloud weeks ago, and it didn't even show up since. A [post at the (German) Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Evolution/Synchronisation/) suggests using `syncevolution`. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I am looking into Syncevolution now. But the concepts are new and a little complicated and I have not found a clear tutorial for syncing owncloud and evolution. I will translate that page and see where it leads me. Thanks for posting it. And thanks for cleaning up my original post. I will post back here when I get it figured out.

Comment: Anytime. I've that page just open in another tab as I thought to address this issue (after ignoring it for a year or so) – but as things go, other tasks got more important again :( Note that, while that page has a command-line approach, using the GUI (package `sync-ui`) might be much simpler. Maybe apart from the Cron stuff :) See [here](https://www.group-office.com/wiki/Gnome_Evolution). And [English howto](http://blog.progs.be/694) (CLI again). [Extensive doc](https://syncevolution.org/documentation/syncevolution-usage).

Comment: Oh, and even a [howto in the official Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution) (just found it now – might prove especially helpful to you, as it's in English again :)

Comment: Izzy, you're great! Thanks for all the help. I had previously ignored those results in my searches because it involved a phone and not real evolution but now that I look at them they look helpful. I tried the GUI but it keeps bombing out with two different Owncloud servers I have tried. It says: "Unable to connect to the Server". I am not afraid of the command line but need to study out what is expected and I am afraid that my results will not be different. I just really need to get real work done not play with my computer.

Comment: I wonder if it is because both servers use HTTPS?

Comment: Should have nothing to do with HTTPS (I'd rather expect everyone using this, and plain HTTP being the exception). Why do you need 2 OC servers? Try with 1 first to see if it works. When adding the 2nd, make sure to name it differently (guess on the CLI, that's the first step setting up a template: it might need a separate template for each OC server). I can only *guess* here as I didn't yet try myself, sorry.

Comment: The second one was just for testing. I have been wrestling with this so much I wanted to eliminate all possibilities. To that end I tried KDE's Kontact which had no problems talking to Owncloud and keeping information while offline. Hmmmm. It actually has a nice interface and reminds me a little of Outlook, which I used to use years ago. Maybe it would be easier to just switch over to Kontact. Double Hmmmm.

Comment: All the load of KDE dependencies just for that seems a bit heavy. Unless you're using KDE anyway, of course. I stick with Evo as I've used that for the past 16 years, have set up several things just around it, and have not yet found anything suitable to replace it. Might look into that when migrating my primary workstation to Cinnamon this year, with a fresh setup. Will need a bunch of replacements then if I really want to get rid of those dependencies …

Comment: If you've solved your issue, please don't forget to [answer your question here](/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: Try syncevolution. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/Synchronize-evolution-data-with-caldav-cardav-server